# How to solve spinorial differential equations.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, spin-geometry

I've asked [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/781189/how-to-solve-the-dirac-equation-and-find-its-eigenfunctions) question in the Physics Exchange Forums, but I think this is a more appropaite site to ask this question. How would you solve the following differential equation, and find its eigenfucntions:
$$
(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m) \psi = e\gamma^\mu A_\mu \psi
$$
where $\gamma^\mu$ are [the gamma matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices?oldformat=true), and $A_\mu = (\frac{e}{4\pi\varepsilon_0r}, 0, 0, 0)$. Note that we are using the [Einsten Sumation Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation?oldformat=true). For more clarification:
$$
(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m\mathbb I_{4}) \psi = e\gamma^\mu A_\mu \psi
$$

$$
\psi(\mathbf r, t) = \begin{pmatrix} 
\psi_1 \\
\psi_2 \\
\psi_3 \\
\psi_4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
How would you solve this last differential equation in spherical coordinates. I do not know from where to start, because the partial derivatives get mixed up, by the $\gamma^\mu$, and you get a system of 4 differential equations. Any hint?

Comment: does a plane wave solve?

Comment: Google "Dirac equation for Coulomb potential", or "Dirac equation for hydrogen atom". You will find lots of solutions. An example is https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node501.html.